# MongoDB "find" query with multiple query documents

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I am using MongoDB 3.2 with Java. I read the documentation and it says to use `org.bson.BsonDocument` since other options like `BSONObject` and `Document` are deprecated. Now, I have query similar to:

```
db.schools.find({ zipcode: "63109" },
    { students: { $elemMatch: { school: 102 } } } )
```

I am wondering: how can I write this query in Java?

**Note:** Here we have two documents inside the `find` function, while it accepts only single `Bson Document` or multiple `Bson Element`(s).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use one document for the condition, like `db.schools.find({ zipcode: "000000", students: { $elemMatch: { school: 102 }});`

EDIT:

So, you are using Projection. In java mongodb driver 3.3 there are: public DBCursor find(DBObject query, DBObject projection). I think you should update your java mongodb driver.

Comment: I tried but it returns all the elements of the array which is something I don't want.

Comment: Do you want to query all schools that have 63109 zipcode and in the 'students' array of subdocuments there is any element with 'school' equals 102?

Comment: In my case, there is only one school with zipcode as 63109, which has multiple subdocuments in students array out of which i just want one with school as 102.

Comment: In MongoDB you can't query sudocuments. You can query documents only. If you want to query students, you shold move them to their own collection, or filter query results in JAVA

Comment: But above query I mentioned is working fine with console, where it gives me the only subdocument I want. So I just want to convert console query to Java.

Comment: So, you are using Projection. In java mongodb driver 3.3 there are: `public DBCursor find(DBObject query,
                     DBObject projection)`. I think you should update your java mongodb driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't knew that $elemMatch is basically a projection operator so I have to use it accordingly. I can manage now!